# Give access to php to a different folder (chown)

Tags: php, linux, apache, chown

My PHP script is located in `/var/www/`, and I need to open a folder located in `/home/myuser/`.

How can I use PHP to gain access to this folder?

Comment: make a symlink? `ln -s /home/myuser /var/www/myuser`

Comment: In addition to the above, depending on system setup/security, you may have to add your www-data user to the group that owns your "myuser".  For instance: `sudo useradd -G myuser www-data` in order to *write* data to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your `open_basedir` option rom `php.ini` file. For example if you want PHP to access `/home/myusr/`; then you'll have to add `:/home/myusr/` at the end of `open_basedir` string.

For more information. [consult PHP documentation on this option.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)